# SQL: Using EXISTS() with some other command

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following SQL code:

```
SELECT m.email
FROM members as m
WHERE exists 
(
select * 
from posts as p
where p.email = m.email
)
order by ads desc
```

I want to add another statement before "exists", so that I have something like

```
SELECT m.email
FROM members as m
WHERE 
(m.ads<>0) 
and 
exists 
(
select * 
from posts as p
where p.email = m.email
)
order by ads desc
```

but it doesn't work, as well as `ads<>'0'`, `ads<>('0')`, `m.ads<>0` etc.

Why do you think it's not working?

By "Doesn't Work" I mean that when I add a line 'ads<>0' there is no change in query result (as if I did not enter this line).
If I add a line 'ads=0' instead - it gives out empty result, as if there are no fields which have a value of Zero (which actually do exist)

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Then your query or data is wrong, and you can probably remove the `EXISTS` from the question completely. Did you try with _just_ the `ads <> 0` condition? Narrowing things down to a minimal testcase is a crucial debugging technique.

Comment: Sounds like there's no records with `ads == 0` **and** matching records in `posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add as many logical clauses to your `WHERE` statement as you wish.

Assuming `members.ads` is an integer data type...

```
SELECT m.email
FROM members m
WHERE m.ads <> 0
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM posts p
    WHERE p.email = m.email
)
ORDER BY m.ads DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use EXISTS as you showed.  You can also write it as a join, of course:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.email
  FROM members AS m
  JOIN posts AS p ON p.email = m.email
 WHERE (m.ads<>0) 
 ORDER BY ads DESC
```

Alternatively, you might decide to use a sub-query to push down the 'DISTINCT' operation:

```
SELECT m.email
  FROM members AS m
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT p.email FROM posts AS p) AS q ON q.email = m.email
 WHERE (m.ads<>0) 
 ORDER BY ads DESC
```

There can be at most one result per separate email address in the members table; if you allow multiple members to share an email address, you might still need a DISTINCT on the outer query.

But, to reiterate the opening point, you should be able to use the EXISTS operator with other clauses as you showed.